# Conjugacy classes of a compact matrix group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact matrix group. May I know why the conjugacy classes of $G$ is necessarily closed? I tried to argue by taking limits but to no avail so is there a hint on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a matrix group, and suppose a sequence $g_i^{-1} x g_i$ of elements in the conjugacy class of $x$, converges to a point $y \in G$.  By compactness, the sequence $\{g_i\}$ has a convergent subsequence with a limit $g$.  Therefore $y = g^{-1} x g$, and hence $y$ is also in the conjugacy class of $x$.  Hence the conjugacy class of $x$ is closed.