# Conjugacy classes in topological groups are closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, profinite-groups

**EDIT** Just realized that this question

[Conjugacy classes of a compact matrix group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228981/conjugacy-classes-of-a-compact-matrix-group?rq=1)

is related, but I think that the answer use specific properties of matrix groups, so it doesn't apply.

**QUESTION**

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group.

Is it true that every conjugacy class is closed in $G$?

I found this assertion in a particular case in the context of profinite groups and I tried and tried but just can't justify it.

I guess this is true for any topological group $G$, but I'm not sure.

I think that we need the Hausdorff condition, because it is possible that each element is its own conjugacy class, so we couldn't get a general result for topological groups, since $\{1\}$ closed is equivalent to Hausdorff.

Since this was found in the context of profinite groups, maybe we could try arguing with compactness too, if the Hausdorff condition alone isn't enough.

Any hints on how to solve this problem? I appreciate it.

If neither of these conditions is enough, go ahead and suppose $G$ is profinite or even procyclic.

Comment: Here is a possible approach (I have not verified the details, so I cannot say that this actually works).  Since $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, and conjugacy classes are orbits (inverse images of points in the quotient of the space by the action), it would suffice to show that points in the quotient are closed.  However, I do not know for certain that the quotient of a Hausdorff space by a Hausdorff topological group is $T_1$.

Comment: No, this is false already in $SL(2,R)$, just look at the non-identity strictly upper triangular matrices, which form a single conjugacy class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really familiar with these groups endowed with topology. Which of the hypothesis mentioned are matched by this group?

Comment: @studiosus I'm puzzled by your comment. Strictly upper triangular matrices are not invertible.

Comment: @MattSamuel : With 1's on the diagonal.

Comment: @Shoutre This is a Lie group, Hausdorff in particular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As observed in the comments, conjugacy classes need not be closed in noncompact topological groups.

As for compact Hausdorff topological groups, it is true that all conjugacy classes are closed. Indeed, let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff topological group. Let $x\in G$. The map
$$
f\colon G\rightarrow G
$$
defined by $f(g)=gxg^{-1}$ is continuous. Since $G$ is compact, the image $f(G)$ of $f$ is compact. Since $G$ is Hausdorff, $f(G)$ is closed in $G$. Since $f(G)$ is nothing but the conjugacy class of $x$, this conjugacy class is closed.

Comment: How could I miss this? This is very simple. Thanks a lot!